# Factor 2 in Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: Which formula is correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Some websites and textbooks refer to $$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$ as the correct formula for the uncertainty principle whereas other sources use the formula $$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar.$$
**Question:** Which one is correct and why?

The latter is used in the textbook "Physics II for Dummies" (German edition) for several examples and the author also derives that formula so I assume that this is not a typing error.

This is the mentioned derivation:

> $\sin \theta = \frac{\lambda}{\Delta y}$
>
> *assuming $\theta$ is small:*
>
> $\tan \theta = \frac{\lambda}{\Delta y}$
>
> *de Broglie equation:*
>
> $\lambda = \frac{h}{p_x}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \tan \theta \approx \frac{h}{p_x \cdot \Delta y}$
>
> *but also:*
>
> $\tan \theta = \frac{\Delta p_y}{p_x}$
>
> *equalize $\tan \theta$:*
>
> $\frac{h}{p_x \cdot \Delta y} \approx \frac{\Delta p_y}{p_x}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \frac{h}{\Delta y} \approx \Delta p_y \Rightarrow \Delta p_y \Delta y \approx h$
>
> $\Rightarrow \Delta p_y \Delta y \geq \frac{h}{2 \pi}$
>
> $\Rightarrow \Delta p \Delta x \geq \frac{h}{2 \pi}$

So: Which one is correct and why?

Comment: You should supply the derivation you mentioned.

Comment: It really is not important though h_bar/2 is what comes from solutions of various QM systems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle . The importance lies in the "order of h_bar"

Comment: Are you sure that's not important? The results are completely different.

Comment: The derivation above is not a derivation of the uncertainty principle. The steps where he introduces approximations contribute to additional uncertainty. A more general analysis will of course allow for sharper bounds on uncertainties.

Comment: Thanks, David. That makes sense. It looks like $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ is more common so I guess I should better use this formula.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48420/2451

Comment: The factor 1/2 needs to be included for the delta terms to represent standard deviations. This becomes apparent when doing a rigorous derivation of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @Patrick yes I am sure because it is an inequality, not an equality and as a statement the HUP is used in order of magnitude arguments.

Comment: Saying the 2 is not important is like saying kinetic energy is something like $mv^2$! Sure it works for contrived cases, but it's generally false, it will get you in trouble if you ever try to do quantitative physics, and moreover any derivation of the formula is just as easy to do correctly as incorrectly.

Comment: I found a derivation without the 2 in Merzbaher's Quantum Mechanics, 1961 using fourier analysis of wave packets. @ChrisWhite acurate quantitative physics with inequalities is almost an oxymoron.

Comment: Related Chem.SE post: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16392/7890

Answer (score 14):

The strongest limit without loss of generality is 
$$
\Delta p\Delta x \ge \frac12 \hbar,
$$
this is always true. Whilst $\Delta p\Delta x \ge \hbar$ might often be true, it is not always true.

The $\frac12$ is often omitted, because, as mentioned in the comments, often only the magnitude of the right-hand-side is important, and not its precise value. Also, it might be omitted for brevity/simplicity.

A further reason is historical: Heisenberg's original statement of his uncertainty principle was a rough estimate that omitted $\frac12$. Only later was his estimate refined with a formal calculation and the $\frac12$ added.

Answer (score 12):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ two observables (hermitian operators).

Take 
$$A' = A - \langle A\rangle ,\qquad B' = B - \langle B\rangle $$

Then 
$$V(A) = \langle A'^2\rangle , V(B) = \langle B'^2\rangle $$
where $V$ is for [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Suppose that $[A,B] = iC$, where $C$ is an hermitian operator. Then, you have also $[A',B'] = iC$.

The [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) gives :

$$\langle A'^2\rangle \langle B'^2\rangle  \ge |\langle A'B'\rangle |^2$$

Writing 
$$A'B' = (\frac{A'B' + B'A'}{2}) + (\frac{A'B' - B'A'}{2}) = R+i \frac{C}{2}$$ 
(where $R = \frac{A'B' + B'A'}{2}$). This gives:
$$\langle A'B'\rangle  = \langle R\rangle  + i \frac{\langle C\rangle }{2}$$

$R$ and $C$ are  hermitian operators, so $\langle R\rangle$  and $\langle C\rangle $ are real quantities.

So $$|\langle A'B'\rangle |^2 = |\langle R\rangle |^2 + \large \frac{|\langle C\rangle |^2}{4}$$

Finally : $$\langle A'^2\rangle \langle B'^2\rangle  \ge |\langle R\rangle |^2 +  \frac{|\langle C\rangle |^2}{4}$$

That is : $$V(A) V(B) \ge |\langle R\rangle |^2 +  \frac{|\langle C\rangle |^2}{4}$$

By definition of the standard deviation ($(\Delta X)^2 = V(X)$), you have : $$(\Delta A)^2 (\Delta B)^2 \ge |\langle R\rangle |^2 +  \frac{|\langle C\rangle |^2}{4}$$

So : $$(\Delta A) (\Delta B) \ge \sqrt {|\langle R\rangle |^2 +  \frac{|\langle C\rangle |^2}{4}}$$

So : $$(\Delta A) (\Delta B) \ge \frac{|\langle C\rangle |}{2}$$

By choosing $A=X, B=P, C= \hbar ~~Id$, we get :

$$(\Delta X) (\Delta P) \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Heisenberg proposed 
$$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar,$$ 
but he only gave a heuristic argument and did not use a precise definition of uncertainty. Kennard (1927) defined uncertainty precisely, to coincide with the definition of standard deviation in statistics. 
$$\langle \Delta K \rangle^2 =  \langle K^2 \rangle - \langle K \rangle^2 .$$ He then proved
$$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
Kennard's inequality is generally known as the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. This is the form which will be used in text books, whereas Heisenberg's original proposal is likely to appear only in popular accounts.

Answer (score -11):

Some websites and textbooks refer to $$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$ as the correct formula for the uncertainty principle whereas other sources use the formula $$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar.$$
**Question:** Which one is correct and why?

Both are correct. The first is is the maximum uncertainty for 4-dimensional case. while the latter is the uncertainty for 2-dimensions.

[I just recently realized, that Planck constant](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/308916674_QED_Theory_of_Everything_-THE_MATH_07102016) might be $\frac{2h}{\pi}=(\frac{e^1}{2c})^4$, where $(\frac{e^1}{2c})$ presents the single dimension.

As 
$$4\Delta x \Delta p = \frac{4\hbar}{2}=\frac{2h}{\pi}=(\frac{e^1}{2c})^4$$

So, though both are correct, the most important thing to understand is, where the uncertainty comes. It comes from the fact, that you cant measure movement without time. And as everything is just movement of light, (velocity) and you can never measure it correctly in 4-dimensions. 
The fourth dimension will always be missing, so you allways get;

$\Delta x_1 \Delta p+\Delta x_2 \Delta p+\Delta x_3 \Delta p+\Delta x_4 = 3\Delta x \Delta p$
Though it truly is  $4\Delta x \Delta p$, we just can't never see it so.

Please note, that even if my interpretation for Planck's constant
 $$h=\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{e^1}{2c})^4=(\frac{\pi*2.71828}{32*299792458})^4=6.6358^{-34}$$

is not correct, the 4-dimensional interpretation for Heisenberg's uncertainty principle remains valid.

Comment: Hi @JokelaTurbine, what I find totally nonsense is your sentence: "It comes from the fact, that you cant measure movement without time. And as everything is just movement of light, you So you can never measure it correctly."

Comment: @rhetoricalphysicist I've read MTW. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241606/using-the-metric-in-book-gravitation-mtw But it turned out to be just a nice math-book.

Comment: @pppqqq Thanks for the answer. Now I understand what you mean. And notice that I used bad-language. "movement" should be "velocity". -my foult sorry.