# Why is uncertainty $\geq {\hbar}/{2} $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Almost all uncertainties (for example the position-momentum uncertainty or time-energy uncertainty) are greater than ${\hbar}/{2} $. But what is the derivation of this [uncertainty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) by Heisenberg? Is there any sort of intuitive explanation behind the magnitude of uncertainty? I know why uncertainty happens but I do not why the value. It'd be great if somebody could provide a simple explanation.

$$  \mathrm{uncertainty} \geq  \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

Comment: See this previous [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69642/6316)

Answer (score 1):

The general form of the uncertainty principle for two operators $A$ and $B$ is given by

$$\Delta A\Delta B \ge\frac12|\langle[A,B]\rangle|.$$

For the uncertainty between momentum and position, we have $[P,X]=-i\hbar$, which leads us to

$$\Delta X\Delta P\ge\frac{\hbar}{2}.$$

As one can see, the factor $1/2$ follows from the derivation of the general result, which can be found for example in chapter 3.5 of these excellent [lecture notes](http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/~kreuzer/Quanten.pdf), while the appearance of the reduced Planck constant is due to the commutation relation between the operators.

Answer (score 0):

Hiesenbergs uncertainty principle is based on measuing two things simultaneously, for example: $m_1$ and $m_2$, and to do that in quantum mechanics you have to apply corresponding hermitian operators: $\hat{M_1}$ and $\hat{M_2}$ to state $|\Psi\rangle$:
$$
\tag{1.2}
\begin{split}
  1) \quad \hat{M_1}\hat{M_2}|\Psi\rangle\qquad\qquad 2)\quad\hat{M_2}\hat{M_1}|\Psi\rangle \\
  \qquad m_2\hat{M_1}|\Psi\rangle \qquad\qquad\qquad m_1\hat{M_2}|\Psi\rangle \\
  \qquad m_2m_1|\Psi\rangle \qquad\qquad\qquad m_1m_2|\Psi\rangle
\end{split}
$$
$$
m_1 m_2 = m_2 m_1
$$
So it should be obvious that $\hat{M_1}\hat{M_2}=\hat{M_2}\hat{M_1}$ or $\hat{M_1}\hat{M_2} - \hat{M_2}\hat{M_1} = 0$ which is a commutator of $\hat{M_1}$ and $\hat{M_2}$: $[\hat{M_1},\hat{M_2}] = 0$

So if  we will do same with position and momentum we will find out that commutator: $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}]$ isn't zero but equals to $i\hbar$, so this is where the $\hbar$ comes from,
the equation that describes uncertainty is:
$$
\Delta A\Delta B \geq \frac{|\langle[A,B]\rangle|}{2}
$$
So after replacing $A$, $B$ you will get:
$$
\Delta x \Delta p_x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$