# Difference between uncertainty relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have come across two different uncertainty relations for position and momentum, namely
$$\Delta x\Delta p\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$ and $$\Delta x\Delta p\geq h.$$ These two are clearly different and yield different results when calculated with. Why are there two of them?

Comment: Closely related: [Factor 2 in Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: Which formula is correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69604)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expression  is
$$\Delta x\Delta p\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
Though most of the time one only interested in the order of magnitudes so the numerical factors don't matter.