# Is the Uncertainty principle $ΔxΔp ≈ h$ an approximation?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The original paper by Heisenberg that discusses the Uncertainty principle has the following relation

ΔxΔp ≈ h

where x  position, p momentum.

Meaning, you can't do better than Planck's constant in the above relation. The expression has a minima at 'h'.

Is this expression exactly equal to 'h' or is it just an approximation that Heisenberg estimated it to be?

Comment: The uncertainty relation actually in the [exact form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) as an inequality $\sigma _{x}\sigma _{p}\geq {\frac {\hbar }{2}}~~$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factor 2 in Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: Which formula is correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69604/)